# How to migrate joomla users mysql file to drupal users. I have only MySQL database backup. I don't have files

Tags: migrations, backups

I have only MySQL database backup. I don't have files.

Answer (score 1):

Install your backup into a MySQl database, and use the Migrate module (http://dgo.to/migrate) to migrate your users into Drupal.